# Is it possible to get the UUI or AAI of an incoming call using Avaya DMCC .NET?

Tags: avaya, avaya-dmcc-.net

I'm trying to develop a CTI integration with the very badly documented avaya DMCC library for .NET. I've been looking around for hours and couldn't find any method to get the UUI variable from an incoming call, either using the `ThirdPartyController`'s events `OnEstablishedEvent` and `OnDeliveredEvent` or the `ServiceProvider.GetCallInformationLink.GetCallInformation` method.

Is it even possible to get the UUI or the AAI using Avaya DMCC .NET?

The version I'm using is 5.2.3.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Release 5.2 DMCC does not provide an application the ability to set UUI data. You need to do that through TSAPI, JTAPI oCVLAN or DLG at the present time. Avaya plans to release new functionality with AE Services Release 6.0 that would allow an application access to the get/set UUI capabilities through DMCC.

---

> At this point in time with AE Services 6.1 the so called unified DMCC
>   API which provides most TSAPI services through the DMCC API allows
>   applications the ability to send UUI information with the typical call
>   requests from the call control services portion of the API.

---

[Avaya forums](https://www.devconnectprogram.com/forums/posts/list/5499.page) on November 2010